# bookmark button fails to load the canvas

Tags: facebook, bookmarks, iframe-app

when using my app bookmark button that is displayed in the top right of any canvas application interface (apps.facebook.com), I don't get my app loaded/reloaded in the iframe, the iframe show the "loading" animation but ends void with only the facebook footer

the link of the bookmark is correct: it will load successfully the app if pasted in a new browser window; the URL of the apps.facebook.com interface change to the correct URL clicking the bookmark but the application is not loaded, but forcing a reload of the whole browser page the app is correctly loaded... it seem that the iframe loading fails but not the js URL edit

I'm puzzled because checking my server log I don't catch any request from facebook for the canvas page, therefore it is failing before

anybody has observed any similar behaviour?

Comment: User Firebug for Firefox or the built in debugging tool in Chrome and look at the network traffic, look at the error logs, and see if there's a hint as to what is happening.

Comment: thanks, but now all is right just after setting the "App Namespace", I think the new auto bookmark needs this in order to work

Comment: Yeah, bad config in the app settings will definitely cause a bad user experience  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Claudio Felicioli figured it, you must set the App Namespace.

1. https://developers.facebook.com/apps/
2. On the left, Click on your application
3. Click **Edit Settings**
4. Type information for **App Namespace**
5. Click **Save Changes**